# HTTP Error when uploading Images to Library

Tags: php, wordpress, image, .htaccess

I wanted to upload some images to my Wordpress from Library but it gave me an error "HTTP Error"

Here's some screenshots about it

[image]

[image]

I was trying to upload 5 images which each has details like this

[image]

1. I tried to activating and deactivating plugins and it doesn't work
2. Adding **AddType x-mapp-php5 .php** to the begin of .htaccess and it doesn't work
3. Adding some code in **function.php**.

> ```
> add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
>
> function change_graphic_lib($array) {
>   return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
> }
> ```

4. Adding in htaccess again

> ```
> <IfModule mod_security.c>
> SecFilterEngine Off
> SecFilterScanPOST Off
> </IfModule>
> ```

5. Again

> ```
> <FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
> Satisfy Any
> Order allow,deny
> Allow from all
> Deny from none
> </FilesMatch>
> ```

6. And again

> ```
> <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
>   # 20MB
>   MaxRequestLen 20000000
> </IfModule>
> ```

7. And comment and uncomment the codes that I added to .htaccess
8. and adding **define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');** in wp-config.php

I always trying to upload same images and it gives me a random image which has error

Help me please.. and Sorry for bad English

***---- Addition***

this is my htaccess looks like now

> ```
> #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
>
> <IfModule LiteSpeed>
> ###LSCACHE START PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block!###
> RewriteEngine on
> CacheLookup public on
> ###LSCACHE START RESOURCE###
> RewriteRule wp-content/.*/(loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
> ###LSCACHE END RESOURCE###
> ###LSCACHE START FAVICON###
> RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
> ###LSCACHE END FAVICON###
> ###LSCACHE END PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block!###
> </IfModule>
> <Files "xmlrpc.php">
> Order Allow,Deny
> deny from all
> </Files>
>
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
>
> #<IfModule mod_security.c>
> #SecFilterEngine Off
> #SecFilterScanPOST Off
> #</IfModule>
>
> #<FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
> #Satisfy Any
> #Order allow,deny
> #Allow from all
> #Deny from none
> #</FilesMatch>
>
> #<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
>   # 20MB
> #  MaxRequestLen 20000000
> #</IfModule>
> ```

And This is my plugins looks like now

[image]

Comment: What is  define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config ? Is it true ? If not try doing it. Or check the error log file to get the details of the error.

Comment: I think some of the plugins make this. Try to disable one by one them and re-upload. Start with plugins which are working with images

Comment: @Samay :  yes, I did.. I didn't get any error there..

Comment: @S.I. :  I will add the plugins list to the post .. wait :) ..

Comment: Did you check the error log files ?

Comment: Just try disable/enable them :) and as @Samay said check error logs

Comment: @Samay :  yes I did, there's no error given at today's date

Comment: @S.I. : okay, i'll try it again

Comment: I still get the same error which I had deactivated all plugins

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @VasimVanzara 4.1.13

Comment: Yes,I have find solution for this.I just check it out.This is regarding php.ini

Comment: after crunching it says http error

Comment: @VasimVanzara aw... how do I configure it? Because It's on the hosting.. Yes after crunching it says 'HTTP Error'

Comment: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');

Comment: @VasimVanzara I did..

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @VasimVanzara yes

Comment: @VasimVanzara ow.. I didn't see it.. Sorry .. I'll try it

Comment: usually this is due to permissions,

Comment: Hmm,, but why some images uploaded and some are not?

Answer (score 0):

The images are being uploaded to 100% which means the server is successfully accepting the image.

The problem lies at the WordPress processing end. ('WP_DEBUG', true); will help you find the error, but usually there are a few common reasons for this.

1. Does your host have GD library properly installed and running?
2. Does WordPress have the appropriate write permissions.
3. Is WordPress running out of memory?
4. Try this: Upload your image to https://tinypng.com/

   Download the compressed version

   Try uploading this compressed version.
   If point 4 works there are problems with your image files itself which need to be troubleshooted.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. I always compress my image to tinypng before uploading it to wordpress.. I already enabled the debug but no error that given to me in error_log :)

Answer (score 0):

Create php.ini file ad below code and upload in wp-admin folder

```
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
```

I hope this will fix this error.

**Please ask your host regarding this issue.**

Comment: where did you add this file?

Comment: are you on VPS or shared host?

Comment: I will try this.. In a hosting // maybe shared host.. The hosting is down.. sorry..

Comment: What should I do after make php.ini, copy and paste your code?

Comment: There is some of host are not allow to edit existing php.ini file that why if you want to override existing memory limit then you have to create own.

Comment: change permission wp-content/uploads/ 775

Comment: I have found this nothing else,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyunD7DW25E

Comment: I think it's not about permission because some images have been successfully uploaded but not some..

Comment: I think.Your upload limit 2 MB as per wordpress settings you are upload more then 2MB

Comment: Other case is you are out of memory please chek you disk storage limit

Comment: Hmm,, No It's not but CPU usage is so high, what about it?

Comment: you have to consult with your host provider.

Comment: I think so :) and thank you for your help, you are helping me so much..

Comment: Try at level  best.I have same error in my project.I am on VPS then do suggested by host assistant.Same thing I was tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, where even though `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` were at the needed larger values, any upload above 10MB would fail. Turns out that  `LimitRequestBody` in a `.htaccess` file (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) was set to 10MB, which then caused any upload above 10MB to fail without any sever error message or server response, just as indicated in the OP screenshots.